# MySQL: Counting across many to many and one to many (and other stuff)

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a MySQL database with many tables. The relevant to this question are:

```
TABLE: Schedule (For booking time on a machine)
       - SlotID (INTEGER - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY KEY)
       - SlotDate (VARCHAR)
       - SlotStart (INTEGER)
       - SlotStop (INTEGER)
       - UserID (INTEGER - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User.UserID)
       - OperatorID (INTEGER - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES User.UserID)

TABLE: Treatment (Defines what the machine should do)
       - TreatmentID (INTEGER - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY KEY)
       - SOME OTHER BOOLEANS TO ACTIVATE EACH SENSOR (Irrelevant)

TABLE: ScheduleTreatment (Many to many relationships between Schedule & Treatment)
       - SlotID (INTEGER - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Schedule.SlotID)
       - TreatmentID (INTEGER - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Treatment.TreatmentID)

TABLE: Individual (each treatment will be applied to n different individuals)
       - IndID (INTEGER - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY KEY)
       - Active (BOOLEAN if 0 this should be ignored and not counted)
       - TreatmentID (INTEGER - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Treatment.TreatmentID)

TABLE: User (Table with user data)
       - UserID (INTEGER - AUTO_INCREMENT - PRIMARY KEY)
       - Username (VARCHAR)
       - Some other irrelevant fields
```

So reserved machine slots are put on `Schedule`, actions to perform are put on `Treatment`, the individuals on which to perform those actions (every treatment is performed on many identical individuals to do statistics) are put on `Individual` and `ScheduleTreatment` links the slot to the different treatments that should be carried on during that slot (and the individuals on which to do them can be obtained using the `TreatmentID` foreing key. `OperatorID` provides a link to a user (not the owner of the slot) which will be in charge to overlook the process.

I'd like to perform a Slot preview so the user can see all the info (so the query should end with `WHERE Schedule.UserID = ?`) which means getting `Schedule.*`, the username of the Operator, and two counts: one of how many treatments (this one is relatively simple with `ScheduleTreatment` and a `GROUP BY`) and another of how many individuals (across all assigned treatments) and here I have absolutely no idea how. Slots with no treatments or slots with treatments and no individual should appear as well (with a 0 in the corresponding count).

It seems to me that this requires to group by two different criteria but it's also something that looks like it can be done in one (smarter than me) query. I've managed to do them separately, but not in the same query. Here's an example that get's `Treatment.*` and all individuals assigned to it:

```
SELECT Treatment.TreatmentID, COUNT(Individual.TreatmentID) AS Individuals
FROM Treatment INNER JOIN Individual ON Individual.TreatmentID = 
Treatment.TreatmentID GROUP BY Individual.TreatmentID ORDER BY TreatmentID
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not reading all that. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to perform a Slot preview so the user can see all the info (so the query should end with WHERE Schedule.UserID = ?) which means getting Schedule.*

```
select Schedule.* from Schedule WHERE Schedule.UserID = ?
```

, the username of the Operator,

```
select Schedule.*, op.username as OperatorName 
from Schedule s
inner join User op on s.OperatorID = op.id
where Schedule.UserID = ?
```

and two counts: one of how many treatments (this one is relatively simple with ScheduleTreatment and a GROUP BY)

```
SELECT SlotID, COUNT(*) scount
FROM ScheduleTreatment
GROUP BY SlotID
```

and another of how many individuals (across all assigned treatments) and here I have absolutely no idea how.

```
SELECT SlotID, COUNT(*) icount
FROM ScheduleTreatment st
INNER JOIN Individual i on st.TreatmentID = i.TreatmentID 
WHERE i.actve <> 0
GROUP BY SlotID
```

Slots with no treatments or slots with treatments and no individual should appear as well (with a 0 in the corresponding count).

```
SELECT Schedule.*, op.username as OperatorName , st.scount, i.icount
FROM Schedule s
INNER JOIN User op on s.OperatorID = op.id
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT SlotID, COUNT(*) scount
           FROM ScheduleTreatment
           GROUP BY SlotID
           ) st on s.slotid = st.slotid
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT SlotID, COUNT(*) icount
           FROM ScheduleTreatment st
           INNER JOIN Individual i on st.TreatmentID = i.TreatmentID 
           WHERE i.actve <> 0
           GROUP BY SlotID
           ) i on s.slotid = i.slotid
WHERE Schedule.UserID = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I corrected some spelling but still I get a #1064 syntax error. The thing is, I don't quite understand how to use subqueries. Here's the (slightly) modified version that I tried:

Comment: `SELECT Schedule.*, op.Username as OperatorName , st.scount, i.icount
FROM Schedule s
INNER JOIN User op on s.OperatorID = op.UserID
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT SlotID, COUNT(*) as scount
           FROM ScheduleTreatment
           GROUP BY SlotID
           ) st on s.SlotID = st.SlotID
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT SlotID, COUNT(i.*) as icount
           FROM ScheduleTreatment st
           INNER JOIN Individual i on st.TreatmentID = i.TreatmentID 
           WHERE i.Active <> 0
           GROUP BY SlotID
           ) i on s.SlotID = i.SlotID
WHERE Schedule.UserID = 1`

Comment: I've tried the subquery as well, it had some syntax errors too (or maybe a different version of SQL, I'm on MySQL):

`SELECT SlotID, COUNT(DISTINCT i.IndID) AS icount
FROM ScheduleTreatment AS st
INNER JOIN Individual as i on st.TreatmentID = i.TreatmentID 
WHERE i.Active <> 0
GROUP BY SlotID` This one does the trick, still can't compose them togheter.

Comment: The syntax error is `i.*` change that to just `*`.  Go back to the slightly modified version 2 comments up. In the last subquery change `Count(i.*)` to `count(*)`  or if necessary  to `COUNT(DISTINCT i.IndID)`